# Most of the classifiers are not avaliable in Weka, please hep

Tags: dataset, weka, data-mining

I downloaded dataset talks about loan, then I want to see what types of classifiers could use in Weka. It's almost empty, I don't know what the problem. I select one of the nominal class attributes as the class attribute but doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check your weka download and installation here: Weka Download page

Then also the availability of classifiers depend on the type of attributes you have. Some classifiers are suited for numeric attribute prediction such as decision trees while some others are suited for categorical attribute prediction. You find that with  categorical attributes, you will be  able to use more classifiers.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Your last attribute -- the one that gets predicted -- what type is it?  (numeric, or ...)  As @Kehinde says, Weka will only show you classifiers that work on the type of data you have.